# Determine if String value represents class name

Tags: groovy

We are generating a configuration script, which we later parse using a ConfigSlurper. The legacy source from which we generate is free format in naming, and as a result in some cases there are names that are also class names. This can lead to a situation as:

```
new ConfigSlurper().parse("File = 'foo'")
```

This would trigger the error: "you tried to assign a value to the class 'java.io.File'"

So we want to detect up ahead if the property name is a Class name within scope of the application, and take action accordingly. 
Currently we are doing something like:

```
pName = 'Currency'
Eval.me("new ${pName}()")
```

And then handle the Exceptions thrown to determine if pName contains a class name or not.

This seems like a too expensive way to do this test, and preferably we would not want to use Eval. 
Is there a better way to test the value being a class name?

Comment: what about not to use class names as a parameter names? use lower or uppercase: `file = 'foo'` or  `FILE = 'foo'`. or use kind of prefix: `cfg.File = 'foo'`. no need to check

Comment: We prefer to keep names the same as the legacy source where possible, to ease human comparison between the two. (The class name problem is a 1 in 1000 case.) We might have to re-evaluate this choice.

Comment: what if not to use `ConfigSlurper()` ? use `java.util.Properties` or do your own parser.